# Cleaning up duplicate posts

Tags: discussion

Recently, I noticed that some post from deleted users remain active on the site, I was wondering if some should be cleaned up. Most notably those who are clearly duplicate questions (or questions that have been asked before that already have an answer)

Example: [How to convert Datetime datatype to Date format only?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201509/how-to-convert-datetime-datatype-to-date-format-only?rq=1)

Should it be deleted altogheter? considering the amount of questions that have already been answered on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's somewhat context dependent. For example, an upvoted and/or accepted answer may indicate the question is worth keeping, but maybe not if there is reason to suspect that answer poster of some sock puppetry. I'll try to craft a query for these posts, and if it turns up obvious candidates for removal, I will progress through.

Comment: I am mostly curious about the high volume of 'duplicate/similar/ questions, and considering it being a user that has been deleted, and the question has been asked on numerous occasions, is there any reason why these should not be deleted for deleted users?